# ngrx/store - 'throw error as Cannot read property'

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store

I am implementing the `createFeatureSelector` and `createSelector` - but getting a error as `core.js:15714 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'showProductCode' of undefined`

I use `"@ngrx/store": "^7.1.0",`

But not able to find the issue. here is my code :

```
import { Product } from "./../product";
import * as fromRoot from "./../../state/app.state";
import { createFeatureSelector, createSelector } from "@ngrx/store";

export interface State extends fromRoot.State {
    products:ProductState
}

export interface ProductState {
    showProductCode : boolean;
    currentProduct : Product;
    products:Product[]
}

const initialState:ProductState = {
    showProductCode : true,
    currentProduct:null,
    products:[]
}

const getProductFeatureState = createFeatureSelector<ProductState>("product");

export const getShowProductCode = createSelector(
  getProductFeatureState,
  state => state.showProductCode
);

export const getCurrentProduct = createSelector(getProductFeatureState, state => state.currentProduct);
export const getProducts = createSelector(getProductFeatureState, state => state.products);


export function reducer(state=initialState, action):ProductState {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "TOGGLE_PRODUCT_CODE":
            return {
                ...state,
                showProductCode : action.payload
            }

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a typo here:

`const getProductFeatureState = createFeatureSelector<ProductState>("product");`

"products" is what you've defined and you're selecting "product"